# Is it possible to add a reference or link to a method or property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, comments

I tend to write quite some comments within 1 method. Once in a while I'm referring to another method or property in another class. It goes something like:

> // if you uncomment the next line, then please make sure you check 'MyClass.SomeMethod'.

[update]
In an attempt to hopefully give a less code smelly comment. Maybe it might go something like (thank you @Weston):

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds two numbers  
/// See method Subtract for the opposite of add.
/// See also Multiply
/// </summary>
```

Maybe something similar could be written inside a method? The answer of @weston helps me further.
[/update]

I'm looking for something which would make it clickable.
Is there any existing extension / plugin / add on which can do something like this?

Comment: Are you making dynamic calls ?

Comment: You can select the text and press ctrl+comma to get "navigate to" with the value pre-entered... that any good?

Comment: You may also would like to use this syntax in your comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx

Comment: in extension to @MarcGravell, you can also highlight, right click and go to definition?

Comment: @Justin pretty sure that doesn't work, but happy to be shown wrong

Comment: @Sayse not AFAIK, no - it'll just say "Cannot navigate to definition" mostly

Comment: @MarcGravell - so it does, but you could always remove the `//` first :P

Comment: Most important: this sounds like a code smell. Code changes should not affect other code.

Comment: @L-Three what can I say. I agree. But that's kinda irrelevant for the question imho.. :)

Comment: @TweeZz: I actually believe it's very relevant, because you can avoid this need by removing the code smell.

Comment: @L-Three I should probably think of a different example then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have resharper then a [documentation comment solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) + F12 to navigate to definition does work.

```
    /// <summary>Adds two numbers
    /// <para>See <see cref="Subtract"/> for the opposite of add.</para>
    /// See also <seealso cref="Multiply"/>
    /// </summary>
    public int Add(int x, int y){
```

Cursor on `Subtract` or `Multiply` then F12 will take you there. Note that I have tried with resharper off and it doesn't work.

What's more, resharper will apply renaming refactorings in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much a bad idea anyway, if you're having to include notes about other areas of the code that might break / change functionality if you do something in one place then your code may need rethinking.

Aside from that I'd recommend looking in the visual studio extension gallery, there may be an extension that suits your needs.

Failing that look up the guide to extending visual studio, an extension that does this probably wouldn't be too difficult to put together yourself.

Comment: Re your last line: scanning every word of every comment to see if it *might just possibly* be a member name / type name - for large projects I can't see that ending well.

Comment: @MarcGravell true, I can imagine this would cause problems, developing some strategy for specially marking the comment lines as containing a link could be done, but I agree, it would be totally insane to do so. I think it's wrong to want such functionality or create such comments in the first place, but it would provide some form of solution if need be.

Comment: It doesn't matter for what reason. Maybe I write certain comments to help out newcomers or whatever. Your answer does not answer my question.

Comment: @TweeZz I'd disagree, ideally you should be avoiding direct comments pointing to other pieces of code as things may be subject to change, before long the comments drift away from the reality of the code. If you need information then separate documentation should be maintained or a higher-level "check out the class that does x" type comment should be used.